# Emacs doesn't start python interpreter

Tags: python, emacs, debian

I've recently installed Debian Linux 11 on my PC and on this Python 3.9 and Emacs 27.1 with the tools provided with Linux.
I wrote a small Fibonacci test file on Emacs. Emacs shows the python menu, formats the code, makes correct auto-indent --> everything's fine. I saved the file and wanted to invoke the Python interpreter C-c C-p, but Emacs didn't find python.

I found out that Python couldn't be started from the shell too. I solved this by editing the local shell script .bashrc with the alias

```
alias python='/usr/bin/python3.9'
```

Testing with `python --version` responds with the version-No, and everything works  fine, however emacs doesn't find python either.
Doing the same by starting from the Emacs shell (M-x shell) works too, but C-c C-p doesn't still work.

I can't find out, if it's a problem of DEBIAN or of Emacs. It seems that either the synaptic package manager installs programs without configuring completely or there is a bug in the Emacs configuration.

I have the same configuration on a laptop with Win10 and there Emacs works fine Python.

I'm a newbee on Linux and Emacs and hope to get a solution, where I don't need to get too deep into internals.

To be honest, I'm a little bit disappointed, that simple things don't run here.

Comment: If you don't care about any other python version, then symlink `/usr/bin/python` to `/usr/bin/python3.9` - or better use the `alternatives` mechanism to do the equivalent (root privileges required). Aliases are defined in a particular shell session and are not exportable (in other words they are not known to any program that is started from the shell - in contrast to environment variables), so even if you start emacs from that shell session, Emacs won't know anything about them. That is not an Emacs problem (if it is a problem at all).

Answer (score 1):

OK, now I put the follwing line into the *scratch*-buffer and evaluted this:

```
(setq python-shell-interpreter "python3.9")
```

Also possible to reduce that to

```
(setq python-shell-interpreter "python3")
```

C-c C-p invokes now the python shell which reacts on  evaluating the python code.

Next step I created in the folder *~/.emacs.d* the file *init.el* and put this line in. Starting Emacs works now.
When invoking the python shell, I see that Emacs starts a script called p*ython.el*. Perhaps this should be corrected, but I can't find it.

For me it fits now, but that means that Emacs doesn't take any aliases from the OS but must be configured separately - at least when using  Linux, because with Win10 it's obviously not necessary to set this variable.